# Computed field on a tree view in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to compute a value to be displayed in a tree view, the problem is that my private function never gets executed and not setting the value for my computed field.

I've simplified the following code:

```
class ProjectProject(models.Model):
    _inherit = "project.project"
    assigned = fields.Char(string='Assigned multi', compute='_roles_assigned', store=False)

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('task_ids')
    def _roles_assigned(self):
        #do dome calculations
        assigned = ' test of 1' #'0 / {total}'.format(total=total)
        return assigned
```

[image: tree view]

as you see in the image the value is always blank

Comment: What you're doing is directly setting value to the field, but it will not work as your compute will be for all the records, you have to make a loop and assign value to every record. check my code below and find answer.

Comment: He isn't assigning the value to anything, but yes your answer is correct. A little hint for Odoo 13: you have to assign values to every recordset the compute method is called with. In earlier versions that was not needed, but in Odoo 13 you will get Errors when not doing so.

Comment: Ah and to the both answerers: this is a very good question, so why no upvote for it?

Comment: Well, he needs to fill-up those values but he hasn't assigned any values to the field that's why it's not showing up in the tree view. 

@jack
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we display computed field in tree view, it will have multiple records set. So we have to set value for each record set.

Try with following code:

```
@api.multi
def _roles_assigned(self):
    #do dome calculations
    for record in self:
        assigned = ' test of 1' #'0 / {total}'.format(total=total)
        record.assigned = assigned
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate over the records and assign some value to it, check the code below.

```
@api.multi
def _roles_assigned(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.assigned = 'assign your value here'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, sice both have a similar approach I'm just setting as an answer the first response, I appreciatte the colaboration